# Opening new datepicker when old one is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using a custom JS library called datepicker, that you can find [here](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js).

I have it set up and working, but I need some extra functionality from it, and I have absolutely no idea how to get it done.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGrid>
        <input id="depatureDate" value="Departure date" class="datepicker dp1"></input>
        <script>
            $(".datepicker, dp1").pickadate({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                formatSubmit: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            })
        </script>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGrid id="returnDate">
        <input value="Return date" class="datepicker dp2"></input>
        <script>
            $(".datepicker, dp2").pickadate({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                formatSubmit: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            })
        </script>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGroup>
```

What I need to do is the following:

If the first datepicker's input is clicked and a date is selected, that datepicker needs to close(it's already doing this, so that's fine) and the second datepicker needs to open, with the date that was selected in the first one marked on it. The user must then select another date on the second datepicker

If anyone has any idea how to do this, advice and pointers would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i've done a small example here, working with the close event.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker1" />
<br />
<input type="text" class="datepicker2" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    // init second picker
    var $input = $('.datepicker2').pickadate();    
    // init first picker
    $('.datepicker1').pickadate({
        // handle close event
        onClose: function() {
            var picker = $input.pickadate('picker');
            // set unix timestamp to the second picker
            // maybe theres a better solution for this...currenlty it works
            picker.set('select', this.component.item.select.pick );
            picker.open();
        }
    });

</script>
```

dont forget to load all pickadate libraries and jquery.....
i've defined 2 divs with classed datepicker1 and datepicker2. then i'm creating 
the datepicker objects. the datepicker1 object handles the onClose event.
When the first datepicker is closed, the scripts opens the second and sets the value of datepicker1...

hope this helps

cheers

Answer (score 1):

the datepicker provides an close event, maybe you can use this? Take a look at the API here
http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api.htm#method-on
some lines further down, you find

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
onOpen: function() {
    console.log('Opened up!')
},
onClose: function() {
    console.log('Closed now')
},
onRender: function() {
    console.log('Just rendered anew')
},
onStart: function() {
    console.log('Hello there :)')
},
onStop: function() {
    console.log('See ya')
},
onSet: function(event) {
    console.log('Set stuff:', event)
}
})
```

when entering the close event, open a new datepicker and set default value of the currently closed.

Comment: Thanks, I have read through it, and I'm already trying to use the onSet() function, which is called when a date is selected. My problem is setting the date on the next datepicker so that the use knows what he has already selected.